# Getting values from a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I'm passing some values to a javascript function from an anchor tag as follows:

```
    <a href="http:///www.example.com" data-json='{ "next_id": 3, "prev_id":1}' id="2">Click here</a>
```

The js function looks a bit like this:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'a', function( event ) {
    console.log($(this).data());
    var this_id = this.id;
    var next_id = $(this).data(next_id);
    var prev_id = $(this).data(prev_id);
}
```

The console shows the following for $(this).data()

```
Object {json: Object}
    json: Object
        next_id: 3
        prev_id: 1
```

But any attempt to read the values of next_id or prev_id fail:

```
var prev_id = $(this).data(prev_id);
```

just returns `[object Object]`

```
var prev_id = $(this).data("prev_id");
```

or

```
var prev_id = $(this).data('prev_id');
```

Returns `Undefined`

I think I'm missing something fairly obvious - really grateful for any pointers

Comment: try  console.log($(this).data().json.next_id); it will give you the correct value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the JSON using [`.data(key)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) where `key` is `json`, then you can get the  `next_id` or `prev_id` property.

*Use*

```
 var next_id = $(this).data('json').next_id;
```